# selecting one specific children i'm hovering

Tags: jquery

i'm trying to select the  element i'm hovering inside a table, in order to change its properties. I was trying with the children method, like this:

```
<table class="tablemain" position="absolute">
<tr height="100%">
<td class="about"></td>
<td class="project"></td>        
<td class="blog"></td>
<td class="contact"></td>
</tr>
</table>
```

and the script is:

```
function() {
$('.tablemain').children(this).hover(function(){
$(this).addClass('selected');
});
};
```

Comment: Why not just `$('.tablemain td')`?

Answer (score 0):

A few issues.

- `hover` takes two functions to be of any practical use. One to call when entering, one when leaving the element. A single function only gets called on entry.
- The children of a table are `thead` and `tbody`, even if not in the original HTML. There are added by the browser when it *completes* the DOM. I assumed you wanted to target the TDs? The new selector chooses any `TD`s under the `class="tablemain"` element.
- I have it removing the selected `class` when you exit the item (delete the second function if you did not want that)
- You had your code wrapped in an anonymous function *that was never called*. I replaced that with a shortcut DOM ready handler (`$(function(){YOUR CODE});` is short for `$(document).ready(function(){YOUR CODE});`)

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/TrueBlueAussie/ynhujf6v/1/

```
$(function () {
    $('.tablemain td').hover(function () {
        $(this).addClass('selected');
    }, function () {
        $(this).removeClass('selected');
    });
});
```